# How to convert strings with even or odd numbers to 0 or 1?

Tags: python, pandas

Starting with the data of this form:

```
    col_1   col_2
0   a1      a6
1   a3      a7
2   a4      a2
3   a5      a8
```

Where values are letters with numbers at the end. And I would like to convert values to 0 or 1 depending on the parity or oddness of the number at the end string, to data frame:

```
    col_1   col_2
0   1       0
1   1       1
2   0       0
3   1       0
```

How I can approach this?

Comment: Is the number ever more than a single digit at the end of the string?

Comment: @Projski No, they can be multi-digit.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
df.applymap(lambda x : int(re.findall(r'\d+',x)[0])%2)
Out[866]: 
   col_1  col_2
0      1      0
1      1      1
2      0      0
3      1      0
```

Comment: as always reliable:D Thanks:)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski Yw~ :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Using str.extract

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: ((x.str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False)).astype(int) % 2 != 0).astype(int))


    col_1   col_2
0   1       0
1   1       1
2   0       0
3   1       0
```

Comment: I do not know why somebody's been messing with your answer, but it works just fine for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the context of this, but here you go :

1. First step: extract the numbers you want to apply check. 
   I think the best aproach is using regex, something like

   /.*(\d+)/
2. Second step is check if the number is odd or even:

   result = number % 2

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but as much I know :) I more have a problem how to combine it with combing the entire data frame for conversion. And can be done without regex?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data in a list of lists(dataList), this works

```
newData = []
for lst in dataList:
    data = []
    for item in lst:
        num = int(item[1::])%2
        data.append(num)
    newData.append(data)
```

Output

```
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[0, 0]
[1, 0]
```

Then you can output the data however you like